# How to display rails app at shopify frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, frontend, shopify

I have a Rails app deployed to Heroku, I can reach it from the backend side of my shopify store. But how can I display anything from it (at least a helloController's view) at the frontend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into Application Proxies. These are available in the settings for your app. This would allow you to map "/a/hello" to HelloController#index for example.

(For testing locally, you then may want to use PageKite for tunnelling the app.)

Comment: Something doesn't work... This is my proxy URL :http://csiga-second-shopify.herokuapp.com/design , and this is my path for this: http://kungfucsiga4.myshopify.com/apps/csiga... but it's always redirects me to http://kungfucsiga4.myshopify.com/login and I get 404 error.... why? :)  (I used shopify_app gem to develop the application)

Comment: @kungfucsiga there was a short App Proxy outage last night – can you try again?